# How to avoid enum values being formatted in a single line by spring-javaformat

Tags: java

How to avoid enum values being formatted `(./gradlew format)` to a single line by [spring-javaformat](https://github.com/spring-io/spring-javaformat). The existing code defines each value in a single line and I would like to retain that as it is

```
 public enum Color {
-    YELLOW("Yellow"),
-    WHITE("White");
+
+    YELLOW("Yellow"), WHITE("White");
```

We use the spring-javaformat-gradle-plugin

```
id 'checkstyle'

dependencies {
    classpath("io.spring.javaformat:spring-javaformat-gradle-plugin:0.0.28")
}
```

Comment: Checkstyle just generates reports on issues found in code.  To the best of my knowledge, Checkstyle does not format code.

Comment: Put an end-of-line comment after the first element: `YELLOW("Yellow"), //`. It would then change the number of elements in the enum to join the lines.

Comment: @AndyTurner your suggestion helps and it prevents formatting, but we have too many enums with lots of attributes in them. Is there any other way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The [spring-javaformat plugins](https://github.com/spring-io/spring-javaformat) do not provide configuration options to control this setting. Looking at the code, it is only possible to specify whether tabs or spaces should be used for indentation: [PropertiesJavaFormatConfig.java](https://github.com/spring-io/spring-javaformat/blob/main/spring-javaformat/spring-javaformat-config/src/main/java/io/spring/javaformat/config/PropertiesJavaFormatConfig.java):

```java
class PropertiesJavaFormatConfig implements JavaFormatConfig {

    private final Properties properties;

    PropertiesJavaFormatConfig(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public IndentationStyle getIndentationStyle() {
        Object value = this.properties.get("indentation-style");
        return (value != null) ? IndentationStyle.valueOf(value.toString().toUpperCase().trim())
                : DEFAULT.getIndentationStyle();
    }

    static JavaFormatConfig load(File file) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            return load(inputStream);
        }
    }

    static JavaFormatConfig load(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);
        return new PropertiesJavaFormatConfig(properties);
    }

}
```

Comment: From the spring-javaformat github Repo:
Since the aim of this project is to provide consistency, each plugin is not generally configurable. You need to change your code to match the required conventions. You can’t configure the plugin conventions to match your style!